# Get the SQL Server variables via the operating system

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables, environment-variables

How to get the SQL Server variables via the operating system?

Example:

- **ERROR LOG** = `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG`
- **DB VERSION** = `13.0.5026.0`
- **DB HOME** = `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2012\MSSQL`
- **INSTANCE NAME** = `SQL2012`

I'm trying to capture the information by Powershell but with no success...

Attempts made:

*Windows:*

```
gci env:* | sort-object name
```

*Regedit:*

```
(get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server')
```

Comment: What does the above have to do with SQL? This looks like you're trying to use Powershell, *not* SQL.

Comment: yes, i would like to capture this information by powershell. I know it's possible through the database, but I'd like to do it through PS or Windows Registry as it's part of an ansible automation

Comment: On Windows they are not environment variables. The mssql.exe process gets the master file/log paths and errorlog path from its command line switches via the Service properties startup configuration, e.g.: `-e error_log_path`. Ref: [Database Engine Service Startup Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options)